# No USB + low-graphics mode with kernel 4.8.0-36, OK on 4.4.0-62

Tags: 16.04, usb, kernel, keyboard

I just upgraded the kernel on my machine running Ubuntu 16.04 x64 from *4.4.0-62-generic* to *4.8.0-36-generic*. Now when booting into the new kernel I receive the pop-up for low-graphics mode but cannot acknowledge it because the usb keyboard/mouse are inoperable, however I can still access the machine via SSH.

I can reboot and go into *grub->advanced->recovery* mode and then I am stick still with no usb keyboard/mouse. I can boot into the old kernel and everything is perfectly fine. I've tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and still the same issue. I have also tried other USB ports.

Comment: Have you installed proprietary graphics drivers? If so, how?

Comment: Possibly, I didnt install the OS.  Could that explain  the keyboard and mouse not working?

Comment: That and the secure boot enforcement for unsigned drivers that started with one of the kernel updates, yes, it could explain both issues. What you should do now is to open UEFI settings and disable Secure Boot (UEFI is what replaces BIOS in modern systems; it's not the same but plays the same role and many people - and some manufacturers - erroneously still refer to it as "BIOS").

Comment: Secure boot isn't an option under either the boot menu or security menu.

Comment: Please consult your manual, online documentation, your tech support, etc.

Comment: Only relevant function (contains word secure) in manual was a watchdog timer for booting, in event that system hangs it performs a reset.  Isn't there anyway I can check which usb drivers the 4.4.0 kernel is using and compare that to the 4.4.8 kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [link](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/71509-4-8-kernel-issues-no-USB-keyboard-mouse-Anyone-having-success) had the answer.

For whatever reason the USB and graphics drivers were contained in the linux-image-extras package, once installed everything worked fine.